# Return simple raw string in ServiceStack (.NET)

Tags: servicestack

For our internal monitoring, our dev ops team asked us to provide a simple endpoint for the bot to hit. Something like: www.domain.com/monitor/check

If everything is fine, it should return a raw string, something like "GoodToGo"

We have an app currently using ServiceStack and it works fine, but I'm having trouble adding this simple endpoint. Any help would be appreciated. This is what I have, and it's having trouble finding the route for my "service."

```
public class InternalService : Service
    {
        public class EmptyRequest {} 

        [Route("/monitor/check", "")]
        public object Get(EmptyRequest request)
        {
            return "GoodToGo";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[Route]` attribute should be on the Request DTO, i.e:

```
[Route("/monitor/check")]
public class EmptyRequest : IReturn<string> {} 

public class InternalService : Service
{
    public object Get(EmptyRequest request)
    {
        return "GoodToGo";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks! It works great. Although I can't accept the answer for another 4 mins... damn it StackOverflow!